# how to use countif() with the result of a columnselect(filter()) function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I try to use the countif() function with an array result of different measurements to get the amount of unique values. I put the result array as a contant to simply things

```
=LET(result,{"2,05x0,7x0,6"," 2,05x0,7x0,6"," 2,05x0,7x0,6","2,05x1,1x0,6","2,05x0,7x0,6"," 2,05x0,7x0,6"},
COUNTIF(result,UNIQUE(result)))
```

in the end I like to have an array looking like this (5x one value 1x the other value)

```
{"5x2,05x0,7x0,6","1x2,05x1,1x0,6"}
```

But I get an error for the first parameter of the countif() function not accepting the array and asking for a range (only?)

Do anybody have a solution to count the unique values and format the result like "X * ValueA; Y * ValueB; ..." in a SINGLE Cell.

I got it working in multiple steps but i need the result done in one cell of a bigger table with multiple values.

[image: Example]

I tried countif() and sum(if()) but nothing works

Comment: `COUNTIF()` or `SUMIF()` wont work with arrays as the function parameter first arguments says it uses ranges or any `IFs` familys function dont work with arrays i.e. `SUMIFS()`, `COUNTIFS()` or `AVERAGEIF()` or `AVERAGEIFS()` etc, hence try using with `MMULT()` --> `=LET(
        result,{"2,05x0,7x0,6","2,05x0,7x0,6","2,05x0,7x0,6","2,05x1,1x0,6","2,05x0,7x0,6","2,05x0,7x0,6"},resulttranspose, TOCOL(result),UNIQUE(HSTACK(resulttranspose,MMULT(N(resulttranspose=result),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(result),,,0)))))`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately I get all ones and not 5 and 1 as expected?
2,05x0,7x0,6 1
2,05x1,1x0,6 1

Comment: Hi @Chris I have posted in answer you can refer the illustration it works on my end. And as I found in the sample you have posted there are some spaces, you need to remove those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNTIFS()` or `SUMIFS()` functions are designed to work with **ranges** and not **arrays**, or any `IFs` family functions don't work with **arrays**. Even the **first parameter** of the syntax starts it with **criteria_range** or **range**.

Instead use `MMULT()` function which works with arrays without any hindrance. The said function returns the matrix product of two arrays which contains the same number of rows and columns in the resultant output. The below screenshots illustrates that clearly.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     result,{"2,05x0,7x0,6","2,05x0,7x0,6","2,05x0,7x0,6","2,05x1,1x0,6","2,05x0,7x0,6","2,05x0,7x0,6"},
     resulttranspose, TOCOL(result),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(resulttranspose,MMULT(N(resulttranspose=result),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(result),,,0)))))
```

---

Using the `MMULT()` it returns the following, on wrapping within `HSTACK()` and `UNIQUE()` function, the combination returns unique values of **result** variable and its corresponding counts for each.

[image]

---

Here is the updated formula that should work:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     result,{"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x1;1x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6"},
     resulttranspose, TOROW(result),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(result,MMULT(N(resulttranspose=result),SEQUENCE(ROWS(result),,,0)))))
```

---

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer but still I don't get the same result. Perhaps a localisation issue? I switched to english but still had to replace "," into ";"
`=LET(
     result;{"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x1;1x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6"};
     resulttranspose; TOCOL(result);
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(resulttranspose;MMULT(N(resulttranspose=result);SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(result);;;0)))))`

But still get this:

2;05x0;7x0;6 1
2;05x1;1x0;6 1

Comment: @Chris well , i can post a workbook link you may see on your end and find the difference that way you can recognize the issue.

Comment: @Chris here you can download to see : **[Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckXyKIxshdKvoOkNd?e=8LjHrN)** also check whether those are spaces or non printable characters.

Comment: Now I see my problem .... your Array is separated by a "." (Dot) and mine as a result of the "CHOOSECOLS" (Spaltenwahl) function separated by ";" (Semicolons)

Any Ideas to solve this?

Comment: @Chris that means as per your regional settings, the separators are dot and not commas or semicolon. I think if you make the changes in the formulas it should work out.

Comment: @Chris this will return row wise: `={"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x1;1x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6"}` while this will return column wise `={"2;05x0;7x0;6","2;05x0;7x0;6","2;05x0;7x0;6","2;05x1;1x0;6","2;05x0;7x0;6","2;05x0;7x0;6"}`

Comment: @Chris i have updated try using this : `=LET(
     result,{"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x1;1x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6";"2;05x0;7x0;6"},
     resulttranspose, TOROW(result),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(result,MMULT(N(resulttranspose=result),SEQUENCE(ROWS(result),,,0)))))` also updated in excel